# How to bind radio a drop down menu with radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding, radio-button

how can i synchronize the drop down menu with the radio buttons so when i check one button, the drop down menu changes dynamically with the same option?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.colors = [
        {model : "Red"},
        {model : "Green"},
        {model : "Blue"},
        {model : "Purple"}
    ];
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>What is your favorite color?</p>

<select ng-model="selectedColor" ng-options="x.model for x in colors">
</select>
<input type="radio" ng-model="colors.model" value = "{{selectedColor.model}}"> Red
<input type="radio" ng-model="colors.model" value = "{{selectedColor.model}}"> Green
<input type="radio" ng-model="colors.model" value = "{{selectedColor.model}}"> Blue
<input type="radio" ng-model="colors.model" value = "{{selectedColor.model}}"> Purple

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: and also viceversa

Comment: So you wanted to change dropdown menu value depends on the radio button value?

Comment: Have you checked: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue ?

Comment: yes, change the drop down menu value accordingly to the radio buttons and/or viceversa. i can do it with radio buttons and text but got stuck with radio buttons and drop down menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is use the same `ng-model` which means you want to think through what the corresponding value should be for the radios and that would be the objects in the array

```js
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.colors = [
        {model : "Red"},
        {model : "Green"},
        {model : "Blue"},
        {model : "Purple"}
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>What is your favorite color?</p>

<select ng-model="selectedColor" ng-options="x.model for x in colors">
</select>
<input name='rad' type="radio" ng-model="selectedColor" ng-value="colors[0]"> Red
<input name='rad' type="radio" ng-model="selectedColor"  ng-value="colors[1]" > Green
<input name='rad' type="radio" ng-model="selectedColor"  ng-value="colors[2]"> Blue
<input name='rad' type="radio" ng-model="selectedColor"  ng-value="colors[3]"> Purple

</div>
```

Several other approaches would be use `ng-change` on each and update the other inside functions, or use a watch on different `ng-model` and update other in those watches

Comment: how can i add an input box where the user can type their choice? like if the user types 2 would be green and 4 purple and so on? and change the radio buttons and drop down menu accordingly?